# Find oldest entity with a certain attribute that may have been retracted in Datomic?

Tags: clojure, datomic

I'd like to find the oldest entity that has an attribute called `:app/type`. The oldest entity might (or might not) have been retracted. How can I construct a query to find this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the d/history function to obtain a database in which you can query all additions and retractions across time.

I'm not entirely sure what you want to achieve, but this query returns the entity with the oldest transaction involving :app/type, the transaction id, and whether this entity was added or retracted.

```
(d/q '[:find ?e (min ?tx) ?added
       :where
       [?e :app/type ?v ?tx ?added]]
     (d/history db))
```